# Which branch should I run dcommit on when using git-svn?

Tags: git-svn, tortoisegit

I have just started using TortoiseGIT to work with my SVN repository at work (I have to jump between branches quite a bit so this saves on quite a bit of down time). However, I've only used Git or SVN, but not git-svn. Should I merge my local branch with remotes/trunk first or is just doing a dcommit from the master sufficient enough to get my changes into the trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always rebase it so there will only be fast forward movement for the trunk ref. I wonder if git-svn works correctly for merging.  As I remember, git-svn, after dcommit, will perform a fetch from svn, and reset the head to position of new trunk.  It gotta make your revision graph a mess, even git-svn can pick up correct revision to dcommit.

Comment: I asked a coworker, he agrees that you should always rebase your branch, and never do a git merge.